# Should I use "is" or "are" when the subject is two gerunds?

Tags: gerunds, subject-verb-agreement

> Studying and living in a foreign country is/are challenging for the
>   students.

Is or Are?

Comment: in "a" foreign country

Comment: @snailplane, user3169: I've edited in the missing article, since it's a pointless distraction from the specific point being queried.

Comment: @user3169, the prepositional phrase here is a modifier and doesn't change the number of the subject (for example, you could substitute "here" for it). This is an error commonly made by native speakers, too.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: If it was just a typo. I agree. But it also could be the OP's error leaving out the article. Unless edits are checked it wouldn't get noticed.

Comment: @user3169: I don't see what difference it makes whether that particular error was down to carelessness or ignorance. It's obviously *not* the focus of the question, and ELU isn't a general-purpose proofreading service. OP would be aware of the edit even if I hadn't posted a comment, so if he *didn't* previously realise an article was required, he should know this if and when he reviews the responses here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In OP's case, most native speakers would opt for the *singular* verb form, because the two gerund nouns *studying and living* are probably effectively being thought of as ***two aspects of one complete lifestyle***.

> [*Careful **washing and drying is***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22living%20and%20working%20is%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22careful%20washing%20and%20drying%20is%22&tbm=bks) more likely to be referenced using a singular than a plural verb form.

Also note that when two gerunds are "conflated" in this way, we tend to specify the more "important" one first, so [**living and studying** is more common than **studying and living**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=living%20and%20studying,studying%20and%20living&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,living%20and%20studying;,c0;.t1;,studying%20and%20living;,c0) (it's difficult to imagine how you could ***study*** abroad without actually ***living*** abroad).

This isn't to say the plural verb form would be "incorrect" in OP's context - it's just not so likely.

Answer (score 1):

> **Usage note -**
>
> Where items in a list are separated by "and", the following verb needs
> to be in plural form. Where items in a list are separated by "or", the
> following verb needs to be singular.
>
> **Example** -
>
> *1. A sandwich **and** a cup of coffee **are** included in the price.*
>
> *2. A sandwich **or** a cup of coffee **is** included in the price.*
>
> Well, this is the most basic rules, yet you will find violation of this rule at some cases, yet they are equally correct. Let's discuss these scenario.
>
> **Examples** -
>
> *1. Two **and** two **makes** four (correct)*
>
> *2. Two **and** two **make** four (correct)*
>
> Considering the rules, you might be thinking in the above example only
> plural form ("make") will be the right choice and hence, only sentence
> no. 2 is correct. But the fact is both are correct. It depends on
> something else.
>
> **Note -**
>
> It's no secret that when the subject is singular, the verb is also
> singular. And similarly, when the subject is plural, the verb is also
> plural. The example sentences above have some ellipsis.
>
> **Example -**
>
> *1. (**The numbers** that is) two **and** two **make** four.* (The ellipsis subject "The numbers" is plural, and hence plural verb
> "make")
>
> *2. (**Adding the numbers** that is) two **and** two **makes** four.* (The ellipsis subject "Adding the numbers" is singular, and hence
> singular verb "makes")
>
> **Another examples -**
>
> *1. The writer **and** musician **has** arrived.*
>
> *2. The writer **and** the musician **have** arrived.*
>
> Consider the two sentences above carefully. Here the first sentence
> refers to a single person who is both a writer and musician, while the
> second refers to two different persons, one a writer and the other a
> musician. The verb is set accordingly.
>
> **More note -**
>
> In the simplest cases, a coordinated subject such as *"John and I"* or
> *"brother and sister"* takes a plural verb, which makes them joint operators of the action:
>
> **Example -**
>
> *John and I have managed the refurbishment.*
>
> But when the coordinates are uneven in length, or when the second
> coordinate is a singular noun, a singular verb may seem appropriate.
>
> **See for example:**
>
> 1. *JK’s article and the negative reaction to it was on her mind.*
> 2. *Bird songs and the sound of the waterfall makes it a magical place.*
>
> When each of a number of singular noun subjects is considered
> separately, the verb is in the singular.
>
> **For example -**
>
> *1. A fever, a mutilation, a cruel disappointment, a loss of wealth, a loss of friends, **seems** at the moment untold loss*
>
> *2. Every legislator, every doctor, **and** every citizen **needs** to recognize.*
>
> *3. The power of the algorithm, **and** the phonological approach to spelling, **is** strengthened when the error list is examined*

**Your sentence -**

> Studying **and** living in a foreign country **are** challenging for the students. *(When you take "studying" and "living" as two separate subjects)*
>
> Studying **and** living in a foreign country **is** challenging for the students. *(When you take an ellipsis subject "The fact" like this (The fact that is) studying and living in a foreign country is challenging for the student.)*

Comment: -1: This is just plain *wrong*. It's true that at the most basic level, noun phrases of the general form **A and B** are "normally" treated as singular. But OP's specific example is *not* the normal case - it's one where the combination **A+B** is very likely to be thought of as a single. As per Loudon Wainwright's immortal lyrics: [*"Water and bread was all he was fed. But not once did a tear stain his face."*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22water+and+bread+was+all+he+was+fed%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for pointing that out. I will modify my answer.

Comment: Are you quoting what said from somebody else? If it is so, could you give a link to the source? If you are not quoting what said somewhere else, you should not use quote markup.

Comment: Last few examples and notes are from my grammar books. And one example I got from other forum, can't tell you now, as I have already lost that page.